# Speed up Select on large list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I am running this on a very large list, it is important to notice that some times the dates in v occure several times, and I want the selected list to show the same amount. This produces the right output but it is way to slow. How can I speed it up.

```
both={{{1996, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.},2}, {{1996, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0.},3}, {{1996, 1, 11, 0, 0, \
0.},1}}
v={{1996, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, {1996, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, {1996, 1, 11, 0, 0, 
  0.}, {1996, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, {1996, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, {1996, 1, 11,
   0, 0, 0.}, {1996, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, {1996, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, {1996,
   1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, {1996, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, {1996, 1, 15, 0, 0, 
  0.}, {1996, 1, 16, 0, 0, 0.}}
```

`Select[both, Function[{f}, MatchQ[f[[1]], #]], 1] & /@ v`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like

```
v /. Dispatch[Thread[both[[All, 1]] -> both]]
```

should operate much faster, especially on large lists.

Surround with something like cases, e.g.,

```
Cases[v /. Dispatch[Thread[both[[All, 1]] -> both]], {{__}, _}]
```

For only "changed" to be in list.

Many, many ways to do this, btw... e.g., if the output desired is always in order of *both* as in your example, and you only want "matched" elements modified, this should be very quick:

```
MapThread[ConstantArray, {both,Tally[Join[both[[All, 1]], v]][[;; Length@both, 2]] - 1}]
```

Note that these output slightly different nesting than your small example, if that's an issue, let me know. You can use `Flatten` or `Join` to rearrange result less non-matches, e.g.:

```
Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, {both, 
   Tally[Join[both[[All, 1]], v]][[;; Length@both, 2]] - 1}]
```

Comment: I see that I have to check if function goes true on the entire list and therefor it goes slow, however in this case you end up with many values that I need to delete in this answere its "deleted" by only picking the values that match the pattern I want, however there has to be a simpler and quicker way? I would like to point out that my dataset is close to 100 000 000 inputs.

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: @ALEXANDER: LOL, guess I was mind-reading... glad it helped, and thanks for accept.

Comment: Haha yes you were! Add it to your CV!

Answer (score 3):

In V10, you can use [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) to speed this up a bit:

```
bothA = AssociationThread[both[[All, 1]] -> both];
Lookup[bothA, v, {}]       (* gives OP's output with {} for missing dates *)
Lookup[bothA, v, Nothing]  (* omits the {} from output *)
```

***Large example***
-- Update: forgot definition of `dates`, which had been lost; had to recompute results.

```
dates = DateList /@ DateRange[DatePlus[Today, {{-50, "Year"}}], Today, { {1, "Day"}}];
SeedRandom[0];    (* for reproducibility *)
both = Transpose[{#, RandomInteger[{1, 9}, Length@#]}] &@
   RandomSample[dates, Round[0.9 Length@dates]];
v = RandomChoice[dates, 10^7];
```

The use of `Association` is about twice as fast as [@ciao's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao) `Dispatch`:

```
(bothA = AssociationThread[both[[All, 1]] -> both];
   me2 = Lookup[bothA, v, Nothing]) // Length // RepeatedTiming
(*  {3.35, 8999973}  *)

(v /. Dispatch[Thread[both[[All, 1]] -> both]]) // Length // RepeatedTiming
(*  {6.994, 10000000}  *)
```

Even more if you include trimming the missing dates:

```
(c1 = Cases[
     v /. Dispatch[Thread[both[[All, 1]] -> both]], {{__}, _}]) // Length // RepeatedTiming
(*  {11., 8999973}  *)
```

And faster than [@ciao's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao) `Tally` method:

```
(c2 = Join @@ 
     MapThread[
      ConstantArray,
      {both, Tally[Join[both[[All, 1]], v]][[;; Length@both, 2]] - 1}]) // 
  Length // RepeatedTiming
(*  {12.0, 8999973}  *)
```

Check equivalence:

```
me2 == c1
Sort@me2 == Sort@c2  (* the Tally method collects them in a different order *)
(*
  True
  True
*)
```